# Alternative for function preg_replace with e/ modifier

Tags: php, preg-replace

Anybody knows how to change this function with preg_replace and the /e modifier. I'm getting a weird error when debug because the /e modifier.Seems that was depreciated.

```
$globCont = preg_replace("/{(\w*)}/e", '$this->TemplateGlobals["$1"]', $content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous function:

```
$globCont = preg_replace_callback("/{(\w*)}/", 
                                  function($m) {
                                      return $this->TemplateGlobals[$m[1]];
                                  }, $content);
```